# How to do tf.not_equal() on sparse tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I get `TypeError: Failed to convert object`. Is there some way to do `tf.not_equal()` or equivalent on a sparse tensor?  It must stay sparse; conversion to dense not permitted.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you want to compare two sparse tensors, and you have numbers in them, I think it's easiest to subtract one from the other and keep resulting non-zero values as "True" with `tf.sparse_retain()`. DomJack's answer only works if you want to compare a sparse tensor to a constant, but that's much easier with `tf.sparse_retain()` like the function `sparse_not_equal_to_constant()` below. (Please note this is not an accurate **not_equal** operation because it only tests existing values for inequality. Since the non-listed elements of a sparse tensor are zero, if the constant we're comparing to is not itself zero, then the rest of the matrix should also be marked as not equal. That's best done when converting back to dense, with the `default_value` parameter, but considering where the matrix had values to start with.) Tested code for comparing two sparse tensors, including function to compare it to constant:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def sparse_not_equal_to_constant( s, c ):
    a = tf.sparse_retain( s, tf.not_equal( c, s.values ) )
    return tf.SparseTensor( a.indices, tf.ones_like( a.values, dtype = tf.bool ), dense_shape = s.dense_shape )

def sparse_not_equal( a, b ):
    neg_b = tf.SparseTensor( b.indices, -b.values, dense_shape = b.dense_shape )
    difference = tf.sparse_add( a, neg_b )
    return sparse_not_equal_to_constant( difference, 0.0 )

# test data
a = tf.SparseTensor( [ [ 0, 0 ], [ 1, 4 ], [ 2, 3 ] ], [ 5.0, 6, 7 ], dense_shape = ( 5, 5 ) )
b = tf.SparseTensor( [ [ 0, 0 ], [ 0, 2 ], [ 2, 3 ] ], [ 5.0, 6, 2 ], dense_shape = ( 5, 5 ) )
e = sparse_not_equal( a, b )
f = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense( e, default_value = False )

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print( sess.run( f ) )
```

Outputs:

> [[False False  True False False]
>    [False False False False  True]
>    [False False False  True False]
>    [False False False False False]
>    [False False False False False]]

as expected.

Comment: One should note the behaviour on 0. And that 0 are NOT returned although they might not be equal to the value (whether constant or not).

Comment: @borgr Well a sparse tensor's definition is that all non-specified values are implicitly assumed to be zero. So if there's an explicit zero in one of the matrices and no value there on the other, then those are equal and should not be returned as non-equal.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to operate on the indices/values independently.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


def sparse_not_equal(sparse_tensor, value):
    indices = sparse_tensor.indices
    values = sparse_tensor.values
    condition = tf.squeeze(tf.where(tf.not_equal(values, value)), axis=-1)
    indices = tf.gather(indices, condition)
    values = tf.ones(shape=(tf.shape(indices)[0],), dtype=tf.bool)
    return tf.SparseTensor(
      indices,
      values,
      sparse_tensor.dense_shape)


def get_sparse():
    vals = tf.constant([2, 3, 4, 2])
    indices = tf.constant(np.array([[1], [4], [5], [10]]))
    dense_shape = [16]
    return tf.SparseTensor(indices, vals, dense_shape)


sparse_tensor = get_sparse()
sparse_filtered = sparse_not_equal(sparse_tensor, 2)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    s = sess.run(sparse_filtered)

print(s)
```